# DataFrame to store n dimensional lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to pandas, so excuse me if it seems silly,
suppose we have tow parameter x and y
for each pair of (x,y) I have multiple lists of data that I need to store.

```
    x1      x2     x3
y1  P11     P12   P13
y2  P21     P22   P23
y3  P31     P32   P33
```

P11 is a list of list. Is it possible to store these kinds of data into a DataFrame and store as a `csv` file?
Or do you any better idea of storing the data?

Comment: Thanks, @jjp, I did not check the green tick because I found that hdf5 also provides the possibility to store any shape of data and is also version compatible. It also has a pickle option.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to store a list of lists in a csv file as a list of lists. This is because csv is plain text and when you read back into pandas there is no automatic string to list conversion.

You should consider pickling dataframes via:

```
df.to_pickle('file.pkl')
```

Then read back via:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')
```

Pickle is a serialized format. Be aware that it is version-specific, so it is advisable to use the same system to export and read the same pickle files.